# System call fork()

Tags: unix

Suppose we have this code:

```
int i;

for(i=0; i<3; i++){
    fork();
}
printf("Hello");
```

1. How many times "Hello" will appear on screen?
2. Tree of processes: parent and child.

I think it should print "Hello" 4 times.

Comment: It is a frequent interview question. You should at least have tried running this application.

Answer (score 2):

For each fork system call that you make you create a clone of the current process. So, you're calling the fork function 3 times which will result in 8 processes being created. The calculation is 2³.

If you want to print the message "hello" 4 times you need to change your code to:

```
int main()
{
        int i;

        for(i=0; i<2; i++){
                fork();
        }
        printf("Hello\n\n");
}
```

Be aware that the code you have will create zombie child processes.

Using this code you can creat n processes you want, let's say 4 and make the father wait for it's child.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
        int pid, i;
        for(i=0; i<4; i++)
        {
                if ((pid = fork()) == -1) {
                        perror(argv[0]);
                        exit(1);
                }
                if (pid == 0) {
                        printf("\n\nHello\n\n");
                        exit(0);
                } else {
                        wait(NULL);
                }
        }
}
```